# Ruby datamapper - search in flag value

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-datamapper

I have a user table (datamapper model) that has a column called `permission` which contains the bitmask value.

`property :permission, Flag[:perm1, :perm2, :perm3]`

I want to find all the users who have certain permissions, such as perm1 and perm2

so I call,

`User.all(:permission => [:perm1, :perm2])`

This makes query

`select * from user where permission = 3`  that is incorrect. 
while correct query should have been (because it is type - `flag`)

`select * from user where permission &1 != 0 and permission &2 != 0`

Does anyone in ruby datamapper, how to make the call to search in flag values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any direct way to do it. So did use this hack.

`User.all(:conditions => ['permission & ? != 0 and permission & ? != 0', 1,2])`

Answer (score 1):

Which version are you running? Under 1.2, I get `SELECT ... FROM "users" WHERE "permission" IN (1, 2) ...` with `User.all(:permission => [:perm1, :perm2])`.

One option is to make a union: `User.all(:permission => :perm1) | User.all(:permission => :perm2)`.

Or maybe shortened to `User.perm1s | User.perm2s` by class methods:

```
class User
  # ...
  def self.perm1s; all :permission => :perm1 end
  def self.perm2s; all :permission => :perm2 end
end
```

Not exactly the same query with either one as you've shown, but the result should be the same.